# Mysql join three tables than group by two columns

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have three tables t1,t2,t3. T3 have relation to t2 and t2 to t1.
I have this select

```
select t1.id,sum(t3.column)
from 
    t1 
    join t2 on t2.fk = t1.id 
    join t3 on t3.fk = t2.id
where t1.column = 'something'
group by t1.id,t3.fk;
```

select without group by have 120 rows. With

```
group by t3.fk
```

it have 5 rows. 
With

```
group by t1.id it have 1 row
```

This is still ok. But if i have

```
group by t3.fk,t1.id
```

it have 5 rows. I expected only 1 row. 
Example data:

```
t1.id    |t1.some_column
5        |"some data"

t2.id    |t2.fk    |t2.some_column
1        |5        |"a"
2        |5        |"b"
3        |5        |"c"
4        |5        |"d"
5        |5        |"e"

t3.id    |t3.fk    |t3.column
1        |1        |1
......................
24       |2        |1
......................
48       |3        |1
......................
72       |3        |1
......................
96       |3        |1
......................
```

select returns:

```
t1.id    |sum(t3.column)
5        |24
5        |24
5        |24
5        |24
5        |24
```

I can't understand why is there 5 rows with same t1.id when i group by t1.id . I know that if it return only one row, i lose information about sum, but it do this also without sum in select. I know this select is stupid and have no sense, but it maybe help me better understand.

Comment: Consider providing an sqlfiddle together with a corresponding and desired result. For the purposes of the example, I'm sure 20 rows will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you do not provide us with enough information because the result make no sense.

- `group by t2.fk` returns 5 rows means there are five different `t2.fk` value
- `group by t1.id` returns 1 rows means there is only one differednt `t1.id` value.
- Since you join the on `t2.fk = t1.id`, which means that number of different value of `t2.fk` and number of different value of `t1.id` should be the same which contradicts with your previous results.

---

> Sorry for that, You are right. It should be t3.fk not t2.fk. I edit it
>   and add some data. – CoCumis

There is nothing hard to understand. Let say there are 5 unique value of `t3.fk` such as [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], and 1 unique value of `t1.id` such as [1], the combination of `t3.fk, t1.id` should yield 5 unique combination such as [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1)]. So returning 5 rows is as expected.

Comment: Sorry for that, You are right. It should be t3.fk not t2.fk. I edit it and add some data.

Comment: There is nothing hard to understand. Let say there are 5 unique value of `t3.fk` such as [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], and 1 unique value of `t1.id` such as [1], the combination of `t3.fk, t1.id` should yield 5 unique combination such as [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1)]. So returning 5 rows is as expected.